# Uploading an intelliJ project to mochaHosting

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to using intellij and have created an Java EE application that i want to upload i have am using mocha hosting and want to use the FTP Access type.

i am unsure of the setting that i need to change in the deployment tab in intellij for the connection and the mappings

any information or help on this topic would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a mapping from the artifact directory produced by IntelliJ IDEA to the directory on the FTP from where applications are deployed. Such configuration should allow to upload an artifact to the target server where it will be automatically deployed.

Comment: i have tried to upload the project and have filled in all the boxes apart from the web server root url should this be the same as the root path?

Comment: Web server root should be most likely the directory that is used for your hosting provider to perform the deployment from.